# Managing Properties in Java

Tags: java, properties

When writing my programs I typically use the java.util.Properties class to load a properties file that contains config parameters.

I typically write a utility class which has get methods to retrieve individual properties for example:

```
public long getConnectionTimeout() {
   String textVal=getProperty("connectionTimeout", "1000");
   return Long.parseLong(textVal); 
}
```

This method has suited me fine but it gets a bit tedious when there is a long list of properties to handle.

I am looking for a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `HashMap` for storing properties which will be associated with your properties file as I will show below. In your utility class, create a `HashMap` instance field.

```
HashMap<String,String> propertiesMap;
```

Then initialize it in your constructor or in an initializer method, you prefer.

```
propertiesMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Populate the hashmap with the data coming from your properties file.

```
for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) 
{
    String value = properties.getProperty(key);
    propertiesMap.put(key, value);
}
```

Then write a generic method to get a particular property with its name:

```
public String getProperty(String name)
{
    return propertiesMap.get(name);
}
```

Comment: How does it help, when you he can directly get the property from `Properties --> String getProperty(String key)` method?

Comment: @YogendraSingh you can think of that, but hashmap will supply constant access time, so this means better performance.

Comment: Agree, but I believe OP is not asking about performance improvement. His question seems to be around data type conversion as he need to write specific methods around them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java EE, you can try using this method, which leverages CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection):
[Applicaction configuration in Java EE 6 using CDI](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jjviana/archive/2010/05/18/applicaction-configuration-java-ee-6-using-cdi-simple-example)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is you can use [Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).
This way you will be able to directly access properties with constants.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Properties.USER_NAME.getValue(String.class));
    System.out.println(Properties.CONNECTIION_TIMEOUT.getValue(Integer.class));
}

enum Properties {
    CONNECTIION_TIMEOUT {
        @Override
        public <T> T getValue(Class<T> toClass) {
            return toClass.cast(1000);//your code goes here
        }
    },
    USER_NAME {
        @Override
        public <T> T getValue(Class<T> toClass) {
            return toClass.cast("Test");//your code goes here
        }
    },
    PASS_WORD {
        @Override
        public <T> T getValue(Class<T> toClass) {
            return toClass.cast("Test");//your code goes here
        }
    };
    public abstract <T> T getValue(Class<T> toClass);
}
```